# Is there a way to return a fully reduced ratio when calling .as_integer_ratio()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I noticed something strange when calling .as_integer_ratio() on some floats. for example:

```
(2.2).as_integer_ratio()
```

This will return a tuple:
(2476979795053773, 1125899906842624)

I was wondering if I could get it to return 11/5 directly somehow?

Comment: Except 11/5 is incorrect. [2.2 can't be represented exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696) (there is no such thing as 2.2 in IEEE 754 binary floating point). The ratio given is the fully reduced ratio for the representable value closest to 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

[Floating point can't actually represent most values as typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696). 2.2 is a convenient shorthand for the closest value to 2.2, but 2.2 doesn't actually exist:

```
>>> print('{:.16f}'.format(2.2))
2.2000000000000002
```

If you want decimal accurate representations, you'll need to use [the `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead of `float`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('2.2').as_integer_ratio()  # Constructing from str is *mandatory* for proper precision
(11, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @ShadowRanger is correct. The value "2.2" is converted to the closest binary fraction. And `.as_integer_ratio()` returns that binary fraction. However, there are other nearby rational numbers that result in the same binary representation when converted to a float. It is possible to find a simpler fraction using a [Stern-Brocot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) tree.

`gmpy2` has an implementation of the Stern-Brocot algorithm and it is exposed as `.as_simple_fraction()`.

```
>>> gmpy2.mpfr("2.2").as_integer_ratio()
(mpz(2476979795053773), mpz(1125899906842624))
>>> gmpy2.mpfr("2.2").as_simple_fraction()
mpq(11,5)
```